# Wordpress Duplicating content using the_content using add_filter()

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

need help, I don't know what is wrong with my code because it duplicates the "You have already voted!" It has all over the site in the header and in the footer. it should be in the content only.

> add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );

```
function my_the_content_filter($content) {
    // return $content;

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $is_voted = get_user_meta($user_id,'is_voted', true);
        if(is_page('online-voting')){
            if($is_voted == 1){

                  echo '<div class="alert alert-success vote-success" role="alert">';
                  echo 'You have already voted!';
                  echo '</div>';

            }else{
                return $content; 
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: did you check the user meta value of this `is_voted`?

Comment: try returning $content in if condition also and concatenate the HTML instead of echo